# Android device ro.crypto.state returns "encrypted", but I can access the /data partition. How?

Tags: adb, encryption, disk-encryption, authentication

I have a OnePlus 3 with an unlocked bootloader and LineageOS. I forget the PIN and I am trying to recover access to it, and I have access to the recovery. The data is encrypted.

My understanding is that, if the device is using FBE, the value `adb shell getprop ro.crypto.state` will return `encrypted`, and the `/data` partition will be impossible to read.

Despite the fact that `adb shell getprop ro.crypto.state` returns `encrypted`, and despite the fact that I have not entered the PIN stored in the hardware keystore, I am able to browse and copy files from `/data` using `adb shell`.

So this seems to be in conflict: I should not be able to access `/data` if that returns `encrypted`. Is this true? If not, why is this not a conflict?

(I apologize if this has been asked before, I could not find any questions on this.)

Comment: interesting, sure it is FBE encrypted? check recovery.log

Comment: I can't immediately check from that, but, `adb shell getprop ro.crypto.type` returns blank. It's Android 10 so it's probably FDE

Comment: That you can access FBE encrypted data files without unlocking is expected, check the file content. E.g. try to open an APK file from `/data/app/` and execute a ZIP test on it. If it is a valid ZIP it is not encrypted.

Comment: OnePlus3 supports FDE. If `forceencrypt` flag is missing in `fstab` then the device is nit encrypted.

Comment: another easy way to check if */dev/block/dm-0* is mounted on */data* your device is FDE encrypted (and in that case when TWRP didn't ask for screen lock - it is simply *default_password*)